# Trying to use Ninject Module

Tags: c#, ninject

It may be a stupid question, but I am following this tutoriel [here](http://blog.netapsys.fr/tutoriel-wcf-partie-1/).

Then I have this following error when I am using the Ninject

> The name 'Bind' doesn't exist.

What is happening?

```
using Ninject.Modules;
using Ninject;

namespace WCFExampleLibrary.Services
{
    public class IocServices : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<ICourseRepository>().To<CourseRepository>();
            Bind<IStudentRepository>().To<StudentRepository>();
            Bind<IEnrollementRepository>().To<EnrollementRepository>();

        }
    }
}


using System.Reflection;
using Ninject;
namespace WCFExampleLibrary.Services
{
   public static class FactoryBuilder
    {
       private static IKernel _Kernal { get; set; }
       public static T GetServices<T> ()
       {
           _Kernal = new StandardKernel();
           _Kernal.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
           return _Kernal.Get<T>();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you using it? Need to see more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here a simple example ( you have to inherit from NinjectModule ):

```
  class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Ninject.IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new TestModule());

            var samurai = kernel.Get<Samurai>();
            samurai.Attack("your enemy");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }


    public interface IWeapon
    {
        string Hit(string target);
    }

    public class Sword : IWeapon
    {
        public string Hit(string target)
        {
            return "Slice " + target + " in half";
        }
    }

    public class Dagger : IWeapon
    {
        public string Hit(string target)
        {
            return "Stab " + target + " to death";
        }
    }

    public class Samurai
    {
        readonly IWeapon[] allWeapons;

        public Samurai(IWeapon[] allWeapons)
        {
            this.allWeapons = allWeapons;
        }

        public void Attack(string target)
        {
            foreach (IWeapon weapon in this.allWeapons)
                Console.WriteLine(weapon.Hit(target));
        }
    }

    class TestModule : Ninject.Modules.NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<IWeapon>().To<Sword>();
            Bind<IWeapon>().To<Dagger>();
        }
    }
```

Hope it works fine for you.
Regards, Andy